# ASP.NET Can you set session timeout value in C#

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the session timeout in code so it can come from a configurable value.

Can I just do this in global.asax?

`Session.Timeout = value;`

Comment: If you want the session timeout to be configurable, is there a reason why you can't use the [sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) element of `web.config`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to change session timeout write this code in your web.config
file

or you can also set this in global.asax file as

Session.Timeout = 60 ; // in Session.Start() event

it will increase your session expire time .

Answer (score 4):

From the MSDN page describing the [TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) property:

> The Timeout property can be set in the Web.config file for an application using the timeout attribute of the sessionState configuration element, or you can set the Timeout property value directly using application code.

So yes, you can assign a value to this property and the `Global.asax` is a good place to do this.